# DNS with parental control not working on (Ubuntu) Linux

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, dns, opendns

I'm testing the FamilyShield DNS (https://www.opendns.com/setupguide/#familyshield) on Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS, but I'm not able to get it working.

I configured it using the NetworkManager GUI for my WI-FI connection and checks from the CLI seem right:

```
$ resolvectl | grep -A1 "DNS Server"
  Current DNS Server: 208.67.222.123
         DNS Servers: 208.67.222.123
                      208.67.220.123

$ ( nmcli dev list || nmcli dev show ) 2>/dev/null | grep DNS
IP4.DNS[1]:                             208.67.222.123
IP4.DNS[2]:                             208.67.220.123
```

I'm not using ResolvConf or DNSmasq or - AFAIK - other services: just systemd-resolve.

The local caches have been flushed:

```
sudo systemd-resolve --flush-caches
```

I even restarted the system, flushed the browser DNS caches (Chrome / Firefox) and in the case of Firefox they have been completely disabled.

Still... This machine can still surf all the adult content it likes from any browser. This is the dig reply:

```
$ dig youporn.com @208.67.222.123

; <<>> DiG 9.16.1-Ubuntu <<>> youporn.com @208.67.222.123
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 19497
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1220
; COOKIE: 4fc7b5602d78fde916d536bb625309a0f4267b41ad8c17fa (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;youporn.com.           IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
youporn.com.        240 IN  A   66.254.114.79

;; Query time: 20 msec
;; SERVER: 208.67.222.123#53(208.67.222.123)
;; WHEN: dom apr 10 18:45:20 CEST 2022
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 84
```

What am I missing? Thank you

Comment: A lot of ISPs intercept DNS queries and have them handled by their own systems, in  which case, they will perform the query as normal. I suggest you ask them whether they are doing transparent DNS queries. You could also try traceroute'ing to the DNS system on port 53 and see if they are trapping it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Bib comment I found out the problem. Here's the UDP traceroute (port 53 is the default):

```
$ sudo traceroute -U 208.67.222.123

traceroute to 208.67.222.123 (208.67.222.123), 30 hops max, 60 byte packets
 1  * * *
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
 5  * * *
 6  * * *
 7  * * *
 8  * * *
 9  * * *
10  * * *
11  * * familyshield.opendns.com (208.67.222.123)  41.862 ms
```

Not very informative by itself, but I confirmed with some DNS Leak testing tool that there's a transparent DNS proxy imposed by my ISP (Vodafone Italy), and later found out many articles about it.

I'll look for a way to bypass it. Thank you for the suggestion!